# Value lookup resolves to a wrong scope in the sbt plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to write a plugin for `sbt` for my project that will process resources. In a nutshell, it is `maven` profiles made in `sbt`. When I inspect `prod:dictionary` I get expected state of this `Map`, however, when I try `prod:expandParameters` I get an empty `Map`. How could I get the value of the `dictionary` from the scope of the exact configuration that command is run with?

**project/ResourceFiltering.scala**

```scala
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.internal.util.ManagedLogger
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object ResourceFiltering extends AutoPlugin {

  override def trigger = AllRequirements

  sealed trait Keys {
    lazy val expandParameters = taskKey[Unit]("")

    lazy val extensions = settingKey[Seq[String]]("")
    lazy val pattern    = settingKey[Regex]("")
    lazy val dictionary = settingKey[Map[String, String]]("")
  }

  object autoImport extends Keys

  import autoImport._

  override val projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    Zero / extensions := Seq("conf", "properties", "xml"),
    Zero / pattern    := """(\$\{()\})""".r,
    Zero / dictionary := Map.empty,
    expandParameters := {
      val log: ManagedLogger = streams.value.log
      log.info(s"""|Parameter expansion
                   |Configuration: $configuration
                   |Extensions: ${extensions value}
                   |Pattern: ${pattern value}
                   |Dictionary: ${dictionary value}
                """.stripMargin)
    }
  )
}
```

**build.sbt**

```scala
enablePlugins(ResourceFiltering)

lazy val Prod  = config("prod")  extend Compile describedAs "Scope to build production packages."
lazy val Stage = config("stage") extend Compile describedAs "Scope to build stage packages."
lazy val Local = config("local") extend Compile describedAs "Scope to build local packages."

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(Prod, Stage, Local)
  .settings(sharedSettings)

lazy val sharedSettings = 
  prodSettings ++ stageSettings ++ localSettings

lazy val defaults = Defaults.configSettings ++ Defaults.configTasks ++ Defaults.resourceConfigPaths

lazy val prodSettings = inConfig(Prod)(defaults ++ Seq(
  dictionary ++= Profiles.prod
))

lazy val stageSettings = inConfig(Stage)(defaults ++ Seq(
  dictionary ++= Profiles.stage
))

lazy val localSettings = inConfig(Local)(defaults ++ Seq(
  dictionary ++= Profiles.local
))
```

**project/Profiles.scala**

```scala
lazy val default: Map[String, String] = local

lazy val local: Map[String, String] = Map("example" -> "local")

lazy val stage: Map[String, String] = Map("example" -> "stage")

lazy val prod: Map[String, String] = Map("example" -> "prod")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analysing [Plugins Best Practices](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html) docs I would make the following recommendations regarding configuration and scoping.

Provide default values in `globalSettings` instead of `projectSettings` like so

```
override lazy val globalSettings = Seq(
  dictionary := Map.empty
)
```

Next collect base configuration of `expandParameters` into its own sequence like so

```
lazy val baseResourceFilteringSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
  extensions := Seq("conf", "properties", "xml"),
  pattern := """(\$\{()\})""".r,
  expandParameters := {
    val log: ManagedLogger = streams.value.log
    log.info(
      s"""|Parameter expansion
          |Configuration: $configuration
          |Extensions: ${extensions value}
          |Pattern: ${pattern value}
          |Dictionary: ${dictionary value}
       """.stripMargin
    )
  }
)
```

Note how `dictionary` is not initialised in `baseResourceFilteringSettings`, instead by default it will come from `globalSettings`.

Now we have taken care of our defaults and we have our base configuration, so we can proceed to "specialise" it by configuration scope using `inConfig` like so

```
lazy val localSettings = inConfig(Local)(defaults ++ Seq(
  dictionary ++= Profiles.local
) ++ baseResourceFilteringSettings)
```

Note how we have scoped `baseResourceFilteringSettings` to `Local` config, as well as `dictionary ++= Profiles.local`.

Now executing `;reload;local:expandParameters` should output

```
[info] Parameter expansion
[info] Configuration: SettingKey(This / This / This / configuration)
[info] Extensions: List(conf, properties, xml)
[info] Pattern: (\$\{()\})
[info] Dictionary: Map(example -> local)
```

where we see `Dictionary: Map(example -> local)` as required.

Here is the complete code of `ResourceFiltering`

```
object ResourceFiltering extends AutoPlugin {

  override def trigger = AllRequirements

  sealed trait Keys {
    lazy val expandParameters = taskKey[Unit]("")

    lazy val extensions = settingKey[Seq[String]]("")
    lazy val pattern = settingKey[Regex]("")
    lazy val dictionary = settingKey[Map[String, String]]("")

    lazy val baseResourceFilteringSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
      extensions := Seq("conf", "properties", "xml"),
      pattern := """(\$\{()\})""".r,
      expandParameters := {
        val log: ManagedLogger = streams.value.log
        log.info(
          s"""|Parameter expansion
              |Configuration: $configuration
              |Extensions: ${extensions value}
              |Pattern: ${pattern value}
              |Dictionary: ${dictionary value}
           """.stripMargin
        )
      }
    )
  }

  object autoImport extends Keys
  import autoImport._

  override lazy val globalSettings = Seq(
    dictionary := Map.empty
  )
}
```

Also consider moving configuration definitions into plugin like so

```
object ResourceFiltering extends AutoPlugin {

  override def trigger = AllRequirements

  sealed trait Keys {
    lazy val Prod = config("prod") extend Compile describedAs "Scope to build production packages."
    lazy val Stage = config("stage") extend Compile describedAs "Scope to build stage packages."
    lazy val Local = config("local") extend Compile describedAs "Scope to build local packages."

    lazy val expandParameters = taskKey[Unit]("")

    lazy val extensions = settingKey[Seq[String]]("")
    lazy val pattern = settingKey[Regex]("")
    lazy val dictionary = settingKey[Map[String, String]]("")

    lazy val baseResourceFilteringSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
      extensions := Seq("conf", "properties", "xml"),
      pattern := """(\$\{()\})""".r,
      expandParameters := {
        val log: ManagedLogger = streams.value.log
        log.info(
          s"""|Parameter expansion
              |Configuration: $configuration
              |Extensions: ${extensions value}
              |Pattern: ${pattern value}
              |Dictionary: ${dictionary value}
           """.stripMargin
        )
      }
    )
  }

  object autoImport extends Keys
  import autoImport._

  override lazy val globalSettings = Seq(
    dictionary := Map.empty
  )

  override val projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] =
    inConfig(Stage)(baseResourceFilteringSettings) ++
      inConfig(Prod)(baseResourceFilteringSettings) ++
      inConfig(Local)(baseResourceFilteringSettings)
}
```

This way we do not have to remember to add `baseResourceFilteringSettings` to config scope and can simply write

```
lazy val localSettings = inConfig(Local)(defaults ++ Seq(
  dictionary ++= Profiles.local
)
```